# Vue, sharing blade/view with two routes

Tags: php, vue.js, laravel-5.8

I'm very stuck here and I'm not sure the best course of action

Currently I have a blade and vue component that make up a dashboard. I have one route that loads the view for the dashboard, and another route (which is called inside the dashboard upon an event) which gets details for an ID.

This works perfectly right now.

The issue is that I want to be able to hit that 2nd route externally (like site.com/status/12345) and load the data for that id (12345) by default.

Right now I hit site.com/status and on page creation it calls `fetchEntries` to get data, I render a table based on that data with links, so if you click  a link it passes the ID for that clicked entry into status/{id} to get details for that specific clicked entry. THen it loads the returned data into a details screen.

All I want to do here is make it so that if I call status/12345 it hits that route, and my controller `details` method. I know I can call that function on page creation as well, but I want to know how to handle the difference between `site.com/status` and `site.com/status/12345`.

What should I do here, and how do I go about it?

Here's what I have right now:

controller.php

```
public function index() {

    return view('Entry.status');
}

public function details($id) {

    return json_encode(Entry::getDetails($id));
}
```

web.php (route)

```
Route::get('/Entry/status', 'Entry\EntryController@index')
    ->name('Entry.status');

Route::get('/Entry/status/{id}', 'Entry\EntryController@details')
    ->name('Entry.status');
```

status.vue

```
created() {

    this.fetchEntries();
 },

fetchEntries() {

  axios.get('/Entry/dashboard')
  .then(response => {

    this.events = response.data;

  })
  .catch(function(error) {

    console.log(error)
  })
  .finally(function() {

  })
},

getDetails(event) {

    this.detailId = event.taskt_id;

    axios.get('/Entry/status/' + this.detailId)
        .then(response => {
    ...
}
```

Comment: `site.com/status` returns blade view and `site.com/status/12345` returns `json`. What exactly do you want? I think your question is not very clear.

Comment: @AndySong Yes it returns json right now because I call it from the dashboard and just expect a result back. I can have it return the view with the json_encoded ID which I can pass through the blade as a prop to the .vue file but I'm not sure how to handle the createdAt portion of the dashboard based on whether there is or is not a ```/id``` after site.com/status

Comment: sorry, I am still not sure, what do you want to achieve, I can understand your current code. Can you please tell me what's your end goal?

Comment: @AndySong let's say I use a new route for my internal call on the dashboard, but I need for site.com/status/12345 to return the same Entry.status view but I would need to call getDetails at onCreate this time. I guess my main question is: Is there a way that I can only call my getDetails on create IF there is a /12345 parameter?

Comment: so you are saying that, how do you handle `site.com/status/{id}` for a blade view?

Comment: I could change that to a method that returns a blade view with a JSON encoded ID, pass that through the blade as a prop to the vue component, then on page load call my status/ID as it is now which returns the full JSON. But if I do that, how can I make it only call that internal function on page creation if there is a param behind status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your question correctly. I think you can do something like this.

```php
public function details($id) {
    if (request()->wantsJson()) {
        return json_encode(Entry::getDetails($id));
    }

    return view('Entry.detail');
}
```

Is it what you want?

Comment: So if I call this from the vue component it will just return as it does now? But if I call it externally it will return the view?

Comment: @TomN. ,it does not have to be in the `vue` component. As long as it's `axios` request, it's going to return `json`, and if you visit the url from the browser it's going return the blade view